# What does "Oh that smells like a Saturday afternoon in the Grove" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does the following sentence mean?

> Oh that smells like a Saturday afternoon in the Grove.

Comment: Where is the sentence from? It's not a common expression.

Comment: There are many Groves. [Ladbroke Grove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladbroke_Grove) in London, maybe? It has had a varied history so it would depend when the text is from whether it smells of marijuana, Caribbean food, or SUVs and money.

Comment: Impossible to guess where 'the Grove' might be without **more context**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phrases like this indicate the mutual shared experience of a place that's familiar to the audience (the audience in the case might be characters in a book/song/etc), or can be used as a metaphor for evoking this same feeling.

In this case "The Grove" might be a place where people (or the group implied by the phrase) smoke pot on Saturdays, or grass is cut, street, racing, or anything else that might provoke feelings of scent.

"Smell" might not be olfactory.  Sometimes it refers to something else, e.g.

> I smell trouble
> I smell a rat

The actual meaning is of course dependent on context, but the *feeling* of the phrase is indicating a shared and known feeling of a particular place at a particular time.